# Problems to use Anaconda

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

After installation of Anaconda3 (2020.07-Windows-x86_64) on windows 10, I have the error when opening Anaconda Prompt below. Jupyter Notebook and Anaconda Navigator can not be opened at all. Could you give me some advice to resolve this problem, please.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 137, in main
    from ..activate import main as activator_main
  File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .base.context import ROOT_ENV_NAME, context, locate_prefix_by_name
  File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 31, in <module>
    from ..common._os.linux import linux_get_libc_version
  File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\_os\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .windows import get_free_space_on_windows as get_free_space
  File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\_os\windows.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ctypes import (POINTER, Structure, WinError, byref, c_ulong, c_char_p, c_int, c_ulonglong,
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ctypes: %1 не является приложением Win32.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 12, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 145, in main
    init_loggers()
  File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 56, in init_loggers
    from ..gateways.logging import initialize_logging, set_verbosity
  File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\logging.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ..common.io import attach_stderr_handler
  File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 7, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, ThreadPoolExecutor, Executor, Future, _base, as_completed  # NOQA
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\concurrent\futures\__init__.py", line 44, in __getattr__
    from .process import ProcessPoolExecutor as pe
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 53, in <module>
    import multiprocessing as mp
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\multiprocessing\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import context
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import reduction
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 16, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\socket.py", line 49, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _socket: %1 не является приложением Win32.
```

Comment: When does that error occur?

Comment: It occurred right after installation